# Upgrade OS version (dual boot)

Tags: upgrade

I have windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Dual boot setup

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS from Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

I am not sure how to upgrade it.

Using a dual-boot, do I need to do any different steps for a successful release-upgrade ?

Thankyou

Comment: No as i have dual boot setup, steps to upgrade from working ubuntu version might be different.

Comment: It's not different for a dual boot.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion as answer for the question.

Comment: @karel how can i unclose the question ?

Comment: There are clickable yes and no radio buttons on the **Does this answer your question?** blue banner, but if you can't see this blue banner you can't access those radio buttons.

Comment: If you have added PPAs to your Ubuntu, it is recommended to disable or removed them before upgrading.  Backups of your data is a good idea also before upgrading.

Comment: The best place to look is the release notes for the release you're moving to, ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes , where you'll find a "*Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 19.10*" which applies to exactly what you want.  Two upgrades are supported, from prior release (19.10 to 20.04) or prior LTS (18.04 to 20.04).  But note: you should be fully-upgraded first, which is 18.04.5 and **not** 18.04.4 so ensure you have all upgrades applied (that'll auto-upgrade your 18.04.4 system to 18.04.5 which currently is the latest *bionic*)

Comment: The release notes also include any *known issues*, ie. problems encountered by QA (quality assurance) testers, and of course their fixes for those issues.. Should issues exist (ideally known are listed), it can be comforting to know before hand, that the issue has a fix, that you recall reading about, and know instantly that there is something you can do to *resolve* it... I'd suggest always checking release notes first (even if most don't include *known issues*, it's worth it in case you encounter one).